# Idea and WebStorm disable "Reformat code" convert destructuring to multilines

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

when call "reformat", oneline destructuring become multi lines, how to disable this feature, I don't know what settings option cause this feature

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I find it's relative 2 options, "Objects" and "Object types" set "Do not wrap" will don't wrap destructuring

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `.editorconfig`, please try changing `ij_typescript_object_literal_wrap` to `ij_typescript_object_literal_wrap = off`

If not using `.editorconfig`, try setting **Objects** to **Do not wrap** in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript | Wrapping and Braces**